# Claims about solution of nonlinear differential equation with symmetries

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, symmetry, even-and-odd-functions

I have a nonlinear ordinary differential equation (of sixth order). If $y(x)$ satisfies the given nonlinear differential equation and its associated boundary conditions, both $y(1-x)$ and $-y(1-x)$ also satisfy the same differential equation and boundary conditions. Can I claim anything about the solution?

Comment: Can you include the ODE? Very curious to see what it is/where it comes from.